# How many ordered triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers satisfying the given conditions exist?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Find the number of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers, $a$ is a factor of $b$, $a$ is a factor of $c$, and $a+b+c=100$

$b = ax, c = ay$ so:

$$a + b + c = 100$$

Is equivalent to solving,

$$a(1 + x + y) = 2^2 \cdot 5^2$$

Which has $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ divisors.

The divisors are easy to state out:

$$(1 + x + y) = \{5, 25, 10, 100, 20, 4, 1, 2, 50\}$$

Hence for,

$$(x + y) = \{4, 24, 9, 99, 19, 3, 0, 1, 49  \}$$

Suppose

$$x + y = 4$$

By stars and bars,

$$O + O + O + O \implies \binom{7}{3} = 35$$

There are $35$ solutions to $x + y = 4$.

But the solutions says there are $n-1$ ways to choose pairs $(x, y)$ such that: $x + y = n$. ?

Comment: For $x=1,\cdots,n-1$, there is a unique $y$ that satisfies $x+y=n$.  $x$ can't be smaller while still being positive and if $x$ is larger, $y$ is not positive.  Stars and bars does not appear to be the correct approach to this problem.

Comment: Stars and bars works here. There are $n$ stars and $1$ bar which can't be placed on the extreme ends, leading to $\binom{n-1}{1}=n-1$ ways for each $n$ (The items to the left are $x$, to the right are $y$.

Comment: Be careful.  Since $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, $1 + x + y \geq 3$.

Answer (score -1):

$x$ can range from $1$ through $n-1$, so there are $n-1={n-1 \choose 1}$ choices.  You are only adding two values, not four, to make $n$